# Login SSH using RSA key instead of normal login

Tags: linux, ssh, login, key-authentication

I use `ssh-keygen` to generate a pair of keys on Kali `~/.ssh` folder.

Great. I also added the public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Permissions have been set to `600` for that file too.

Results are:

- Putty: logged in as trunks@lanIP with ip_rsa.ppk - `invalid format`.
- PowerShell telnet: ssh trunks@lanip -i path to private key file - `invalid format`.

I even converted to openSSH to no avail. What am I doing it wrong? I keep logging in to my regular login account such as username and password, that's not what I wanted. SIGH. Never had this problem before. Putty need to update their software. Seriously.

I checked the public key and it's one string long, proper format. I have no problems witn DD-WRT using putty telnet with public key string.

Comment: First, `putty` needs a specific format for its '.ppk' files. It looks something like: https://pastebin.com/EjQ5DA5R, containing private and public key in a fixed format. You may create such a file with `puttygen`, and then convert to openSSH format afterwards. I do not know anything about powerShell, unfortunately. Edit: Updated link.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact commands that you're running and the exact error messages that you're getting. Don't paraphrase the error messages.

Comment: Do I convert it to openSSH and save it as for both private and public key?

Comment: @Kenster Kali doesn't have /etc/var/secure to look at the error messages for secure ssh connection. I looked, it isn't there.

Comment: Now it's showing "server refuse our key" sigh.. lol. Again, no error message on /etc/var/secure

Comment: EDIT: I think I got this to work...

ssh trunks@LAN IP -i C:\Users\NEO\Desktop\SSH\Kali\id_rsa_openSSH
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\NEO\Desktop\SSH\Kali\id_rsa_openSSH':
trunks@LAN IP password:

How do I remove password login for username trunk and instead use openSSH password? I already uploaded openSSH to ~/.ssh directory and chmod it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-keygen` can generate files in three formats:

- OpenSSH own format (RFC4716, the default),
- PKCS8 and
- PEM format.

You can distinguish them by the first line of the private key:

- if it says `"-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----"`, it's RFC4716,
- if it says `"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"`, it is PEM,
- and if it is just `"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"` it is PKCS8.

In all cases, the public key looks the same. It is also able to convert freely between those formats.

What you use in PowerShell is OpenSSH. You can verify that by running `ssh -V`. It should work with keys in any of these formats out of the box.

To convert a file generated by the `ssh-keygen` into Putty's ppk format, use `puttygen`. Or, you may generate the key with `puttygen` and it is able to convert it into the OpenSSH format.

The public key contains three parts, "type key comment", of which the last is optional and can be changed freely. It can be used in the `authorized_keys` file to tag keys (e.g. to explain where the corresponding private key is or whose key it is). Other parts should be copied verbatim. Notice, that the public key always contained in a *single line*, and it should be appended as an individual line to the `authorized_keys` file.

If you are already able to ssh to the target host using any authentication mechanism, try `ssh-copy-id target-host`, which will create the `.ssh/authorized_keys` with correct privileges if it doesn't exist and add private key there, or it will append the key if file exists but the key is not in the file. The other way to build such a file is something like `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys`.

Answer (score -1):

I would ensure that the copy/pasted private key has the same file size as the original one.
Text editors can add or ignore a line break at the end of the file, causing this issue.

Comment: Nikitia - that's what I did. I append the public key to authorized_keys and chmod it to 600. Sorry, I am learning :D. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is I am logging into standard username/password mechanism, not the SSH mechanism. This is why I am very confused.

Comment: Edited  sshd_config to enable passwordless authentication using public key. No go. If PuttyGen is going to generate keys maybe they need to make PROPER FORMATTING! AND ELIMINATE WHITESPACE! This is messed up.

Comment: Jonathan, please follow @Kenster 's advice, and edit your question. Include the exact command and the error message. Also specify, have you generated the pair of keys on the service or client-side.